# How to discover which name/address connections from one network to another uses?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, mysql

In MySQL you have to authorized a user based on the name of the origin network. From my network to a remote one all connections appear as sent from `mail.mycompany.com`. But connections to another remote network it appears with a different origin. How to discover which name/ip it is using?

I tried `tcpdump` and `netstat` in the destination but it is difficult to find my connection among billions of others.

In my case the destination is a Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 1):

If your company uses NAT, ask the sysadmin what your external IP address is. Then on the destination 2003 server use nslookup to discover what that IP address resolves to. If there's no sysadmin, you could try something like whatsmyip.org , but that may fail if your web traffic goes through a proxy somewhere.

If you use real IP addresses, then look that address up on the target 2003 server.